# Why doesn't it show me the items added in the array?

Tags: arrays, swift

Why doesn't it show me the items added in the array? (I want to keep this array layout).

Could someone tell me how should I complete the array to register the elements correctly?

It always returns zero.

Sample Code:

```
import UIKit

class FilterCategory: Equatable{
    
    static func == (lhs: FilterCategory, rhs: FilterCategory) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    var id : Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
    var image: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, image: UIImage) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
}

class demo : UIViewController {
    
    var images = [FilterCategory]()
    var thumbnailImagesList = [Int: [UIImage?]]()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        images.append(FilterCategory.init(id: 1, name: "1.1", image: UIImage()))
        images.append(FilterCategory.init(id: 1, name: "1.2", image: UIImage()))
        images.append(FilterCategory.init(id: 2, name: "2.1", image: UIImage()))
        images.append(FilterCategory.init(id: 2, name: "2.2", image: UIImage()))
        
        var index = 0
        
        for img in images {
            self.thumbnailImagesList[img.id]?[index] = UIImage()
            index = index+1
        }
        
        print(thumbnailImagesList.count)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary is empty from start but you are treating it like it contains values, use the below code instead that will either add the image object to a new or existing array depending on if the key (img.id) exists or not in the dictionary

```
for img in images {
    self.thumbnailImagesList[img.id, default:[]].append(UIImage())
}
```

A question is why you are creating new image objects everywhere in your code, maybe you meant

```
for img in images {
    self.thumbnailImagesList[img.id, default:[]].append(img.image)
}
```